# How do I move the contents of multiple folders to its root folder using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say I have a directory called folder_1. Folder_1 has many directories but they all start with 1. Each of these directories has text files, images, etc. I want to move all the content in each of these directories to the parent folder_1.

My assumption is that I have to use something like:

```
mv -v /folder_1/*1 /folder_1/
```

But I get the error message that everything is the same file.

Comment: I'm suggesting an edit for readability, this is hard to wrap my head around in it's current state.

Comment: From what I can tell, your MV command trying to move everything from 'folder_1' to 'folder_1', not the root. Root is simply '/'. Written out in english, your command appears to say something like "Move the contents of folder 1 that start with a 1 to folder 1", which the interpreter won't do since they're already there.

Comment: Possible interesting reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105150/using-find-but-only-in-subdirectories-matching-certain-pattern (where in your case the pattern is `folder1/1*`. And you want to exec a mv {} +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mv -v /folder_1/1*/* /folder_1
```

This would move all files/folders from subfolders starting with `1` into the parent. However, this would omit "hidden" files/folder, whose name starts with a dot `.`.

To move those as well, try:

```
find /folder_1/1*/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -v \{\} /folder_1 \;
```

Comment: The first worked fabulously.